# LOC function on pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I create a code see below:

```
check = ['jonge man']
data.loc[
    data['Zoekterm'].str.contains(
    f"{'|'.join(check)}"
    ),"Zoekterm_new",
    data['Zoekterm']
```

I get Too many indexers erorr
What did i wrong

Comment: @MichaelButscher So i have to write in my code? i write 'Zoekterm' as last line, but i get an erorr that zoekterm in not defined? can you write where i have to change the code to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with second argument for column name like:

```
data.loc[data['Zoekterm'].str.contains(f"{'|'.join(check)}"), "Zoekterm_new"]
```

If need assign values add `=` - so for `Zoekterm_new` are added data from `Zoekterm` if matching condition, else `NaN`:

```
data.loc[data['Zoekterm'].str.contains(f"{'|'.join(check)}"), "Zoekterm_new"] = data['Zoekterm']
```

working like:

```
data["Zoekterm_new"] = np.where(data['Zoekterm'].str.contains(f"{'|'.join(check)}"), data['Zoekterm'], np.NaN)
```